# SQL Server : select distinct, but indicate whether another column is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not sure if that title fits but here is my scenario...

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Key1     Key2   Scheduled    Data
----------------------------------
abc123    io       null      asdf    
abc123    go     01/02/13    asdf
abc321    er       null      asdf 
abc321    fr       null      asdf
```

I need to select distinct to get a distinct set of `Key1` regardless of the other columns but I also need a boolean to indicate weather any scheduled column is set. So ideally my result set would look like this

```
Key1     IsAnyScheduled
-------------------
abc123      True
abc321      False
```

I am not a SQL guru an cannot see how to do this. Also our system is based on SQL Server but it runs a subset of sql so if possible can someone help me write this with the most basic of functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `MAX`, `CASE` and a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT  Key1,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Scheduled) IS NULL
            THEN 'False'
            ELSE 'TRUE'
        END AS IsAnyScheduled
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Key1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46e45/3)

Comment: You are awesome, Thanks, that worked perfectly. Because I want to also understand how that worked would you be willing to explain how that works. I dont see a distinct in there yet it still works...

Comment: so here it goes, the `MAX` function which is an aggregate function gets the maximum value in a row. When rows contain NULL and NON-NULL value, the maximum value is the `NON-NULL` value. the result of that is then pass through a condition that if the value of `MAX` is `NULL`, it then returns `FALSE` otherwise `TRUE`.

Comment: Sweet, One more question. Now instead of True False, I need to check weather scheduled date has passed so the test would be if not null and > today then Sent, if null then empty and if not null but not past today then scheduled.  Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need a group by:

```
select key1, (case when count(Scheduled) = 0 then 'false' else 'true' end) as IsAnyScheduled
from t
group by key1
```